# Laravel checkbox with old inputs and default value not working as it should

Tags: laravel

I'm making an edit page which has checkboxes and I want that laravel would remember old inputs. I store in database 1 or 0 values for a specific option.

```
@foreach( $options['tuning'] as $key => $option)
    <div class="col-3 rent-car-security">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $option }}" id="{{ $option }}"
               value="1" {{ old($option, $car->tuning_options->{ $option }) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label for="{{ $option }}">{{ $key }}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
private $tuning_options = [
  'Made for racing' => 'made_for_racing',
  'Increased engine power' => 'increased_engine_power'
];
------------
$options = [
  'tuning' => $this->tuning_options
];

return view('cars.edit', compact(['car', 'options']));
```

Form works correctly if option was 0 in the begining

Comment: can you provide you edit method controller code aswell?

Comment: updated with controller code

Comment: awesome thanks - check my answer below - the best way to get the old values is to pluck the 'value' or 'option id' into an array and then use an inline ternary statement to check to see if that options value is in the array and if it is give that option the 'selected' value

Comment: I'll try to implement your approach. But I was wondering why my implementation doesn't work

Comment: aww ok - the {{ old() }} method is used more for a form page where if there is an error and it goes back to the form page, the values that you filled in are remembered, old() doesn't get the values from the database to populate them it just remembers what you've filled in

Comment: I thought it takes default value at first, and later remembers value on input and kinda forgets about default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it is to pluck the selected options from the database and turn them into an array, example below:

**controller (edit method):**

```
public function edit($id) {
    $options = Options::all();
    $selected_options = $options->pluck('id')->toArray()

    return view('example.view', compact('selected_options')); 
}
```

**and then in my view I would do the following logic:**

```
@foreach( $options['tuning'] as $key => $option)
    <div class="col-3 rent-car-security">
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $option }}" id="{{ $option }}" value="1" {{ in_array($option, $selected_options) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        <label for="{{ $option }}">{{ $key }}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I hope that helps, let me know. This is based on the limited code that you supplied, and is purely an example to get you started - if you provide more I'd be happy to help you solve the problem completely

Answer (score 0):

I've added a hidden input and now it works perfectly

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ $option }}" value="0">
```